# How to create custom shortcut in Excel for entering data?

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

When Entering Data in Microsoft Excel, sometimes I have to repeat the whole string to write down. I want to create custom keyboard shortcuts for this:

For example: Disease

- Chronic Renal Failure,
- Acute Renal Failure,
- Hypothermia of Newborn,
- Neonatal Jaundice,
- Neonatal Sepsis,

Every time I have to write down whole string. I want to create custom keyboard shortcuts for entering data, i.e. if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (for instance) it should put 'Chronic Renal Failure' in the cell.

Any ideas on how I could realize this, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can record macro typing (paste) some text and then assign the macro to the keyboard shortcut:

[image: Assigning macro to shortcut]

ps. But remember that if you define your own shortcuts, you may override excel defaults shortcuts.

Comment: Hello Sir, If I want to create keyboard shortcuts like Alt+Shift+A  so what should I do?

Comment: I don't know if excel allow for defining custom three-keys shortcut